# use variable into a set string in sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm having a problem. I'm trying to select data with a local variable and don't works.

My sentence:

```
set @consultaCant = 'select COUNT(' + @columna + ') from ' + @tabla + ' where '  + @columna + " = ' + @datoBuscado
```

I've tryed to use SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON and OFF and still don't works.

all the variables are previusly definied on the procedure.

Comment: Try this:  `@columna + ' = ''' + @datoBuscado + ''''`

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't works. Now the error is:

select COUNT(EMPRESA) from TABLUG where EMPRESA= 'FCV''

it have 2 ''

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare
    @consultaCant varchar(1000),
    @columna varchar(20) = 'EMPRESA',
    @tabla varchar(20) = 'TABLUG',
    @datoBuscado varchar(20) = 'FCV'
set @consultaCant = 'select COUNT(' + @columna + ') from '
                    + @tabla + ' where ' + @columna + ' = ''' + @datoBuscado +''''

select @consultaCant
```

Result:

```
select COUNT(EMPRESA) from TABLUG where EMPRESA = 'FCV'
```